# Good introductory book to computational physics

Tags: condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, computational-physics, density-functional-theory

First time asking a question here. As per the title I'm trying to find a decent book that serves as an introduction to computational methods used in physics. A little background on myself will help understanding my problem: I'm a PhD student in experimental physics, recently I found myself dealing with a lot of works dealing with electron and phonon bandstructure calculations (mostly using DFT methods). I find these work really useful and fascinating, but there's a problem: I don't really understand what they are doing.
So I'd like to close this gap by learning more on computational methods in  physics, especially methods useful in condensed matter (as bandstructure calculations, for example). I know there are plenty of good books and reviews on the topic, but I find it difficult to relate the integrals and formulae written in these books to actual code. My question in simple words is: do you know any book, online course, lecture notes, review that explain some of these concepts with practical examples? I have the feeling that once I've seen few of them I would be able to kick off by myself.
Thank you

Comment: Which languages do you know ?

Comment: Python mostly, I can get around with C/C++

Comment: mark newman- computational physics